# How to store calculated value in model field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to store two calculated fields in my extended user model Ai and Ei. these are calculated in views. my code is following

```
models. py

class User(AbstractUser):
Ai = models.TextField(null=True)
Ei = models.TextField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

and i am calculating Ai and Ei when user goes to link /join/so url.py is

```
url(r'^join/$', views.user_join),
```

In user join view

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def user_join(request):

#Calculate Ai and Ei from Random

    User.Ai = str(Ai)
    User.Ei = str(Ei)
    User.save()
```

Now my problem is how do I store or Update values of Ai and Ei in the model for particular user

Comment: Storing a calculated value is no different from storing any other value.

Comment: but how do I do that ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer now. Just required to request the user. following are changes.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def user_join(request):
U = request.user
#Calculate Ai and Ei from Random

U.Ai = str(Ai)
U.Ei = str(Ei)
U.save()
```